# Pandas: Selecting rows based on value counts of a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

Whats the simplest way of selecting all rows from a panda dataframe, who's sym occurs exactly twice in the entire table? For example, in the table below, I would like to select all rows with sym in ['b','e'], since the value_counts for these symbols equal 2.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'sym':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd','d','d','e','e'],'price':np.random.randn(9)})

                     price sym
    0              -0.0129   a
    1              -1.2940   b
    2               1.8423   b
    3              -0.7160   c
    4              -2.3216   d
    5              -0.0120   d
    6              -0.5914   d
    7               0.6280   e
    8               0.5361   e

df.sym.value_counts()
Out[237]: 
d    3
e    2
b    2
c    1
a    1
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `sym` and [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) values with `length == 2`:

```
print df.groupby("sym").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
      price sym
1  0.400157   b
2  0.978738   b
7 -0.151357   e
8 -0.103219   e
```

Second solution use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.sym.value_counts()

print s[s == 2].index
Index([u'e', u'b'], dtype='object')

print df[df.sym.isin(s[s == 2].index)]
      price sym
1  0.400157   b
2  0.978738   b
7 -0.151357   e
8 -0.103219   e
```

And fastest solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df.groupby("sym")["sym"].transform('size') == 2])
    price sym
1 -1.2940   b
2  1.8423   b
7  0.6280   e
8  0.5361   e
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use `map`, which should be faster than using `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df[df['sym'].map(df['sym'].value_counts()) == 2]
```

e.g.

```
%%timeit
df[df['sym'].map(df['sym'].value_counts()) == 2]
Out[1]:
1.83 ms ± 23.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
df[df.groupby("sym")["sym"].transform('size') == 2]
Out[2]:
2.08 ms ± 41.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: For the problem I`m working on, this answer is 15 times faster

Comment: How would you do it for multiple conditions? eg for 'sym' ==2 & 4

Comment: The original answer might be right But if you are working with large data then it might take eternity. Use this answer to save time.