# Find the most common row across multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe with an identifying column (Name) and three value columns (A, B, C).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'], 'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], 'C': [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]})
```

For each name, I want to find the most common combination of values across the 3 value columns.

The result should be:

```
['John', 2, 2, 1] # as the combination 2, 2, 1 appears twice
['Sam', 3, 3, 3] # as the combination 3, 3, 3 appears twice
```

First time asking a question on stack overflow -> any advice on how to improve the question is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the link @pylang. That question relates to most common value in a single column (applied to multiple columns at once) - I am interested in most common combination of values across multiple columns.

Comment: `df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['Name'].value_counts().nlargest(2)`

Comment: To make @skrubber's solution more general `df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['Name'].value_counts().nlargest(len(set(df['Name'])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is based on the comments by @noslenkwah and @skrubber.

If you need most common row **for each name** as described

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'] , 'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] , 
                'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3] , 'C': [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]})
df_count = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])['Name'].value_counts().reset_index(name="Count")
l = list()
for name in set(df_count.Name):
    freq = df_count[df_count.Name == name].Count.max()
    l.append(df_count[(df_count.Name == name) & (df_count.Count == freq)].values.tolist()[0])
print(l)
[[3, 3, 3, 'Sam', 3], [2, 2, 1, 'John', 2]]
```

First the method group `df` by `["A", "B", "C"]`. Then loop over names, and first calculate the most common rows' frequency within this name. Then filter out groups that have different frequncy and with different names in the query `df_count[(df_count.Name == name) & (df_count.Count == freq)]`.

A more general problem: finding rows with highest frequency regardless names, you can try

```
df_count = df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])['Name'].value_counts().reset_index(name="Count")
max_freq = df_count["Count"].max()
df_count[df_count["Count"] == max_freq]

    A   B   C   Name    Count
3   2   2   1   John    2
4   3   3   3   Sam     2
```

Reference

[Pandas: Selecting rows based on value counts of a particular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166090/pandas-selecting-rows-based-on-value-counts-of-a-particular-column)

[Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution does work for the example case I posed, but does not work if the groups have different frequencies, e.g. for this input: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam']
    , 'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    , 'B': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3]
    , 'C': [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]})

Comment: What do you mean if groups have different frequencies? You mean you want  not only the most frequent ones? You mean you it for each name?

Comment: I want the most frequent row for both John, and for Sam, even if one has a higher frequency than the other.

Comment: Your edit seems to work, but overwrites itself (i.e. solution for John is replaced with solution for Sam) - working on fixing this now.