# How to select rows in Pandas dataframe where value appears more than once

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the Pandas dataframe with columns of different measurement attributes and corresponding measurement values.

```
ID     Parameter     Value
0      'A'           4.3
1      'B'           3.1
2      'C'           8.9
3      'A'           2.1
4      'A'           3.9
.      .             .
.      .             .
.      .             .
100    'B'           3.8
```

How can I filter this dataframe to only have measurements that appear more than X number of times? For example, for this dataframe I want to get all rows with more than 5 measurements (lets say only parameters 'A' and 'B' appear more than 5 times) to get a dataframe like below.

```
ID     Parameter     Value
0      'A'           4.3
1      'B'           3.1
3      'A'           2.1
.      .             .
.      .             .
.      .             .
100    'B'           3.8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Selecting rows based on value counts of a particular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166090/pandas-selecting-rows-based-on-value-counts-of-a-particular-column)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` + `isin` -

```
v = df.Parameter.value_counts()
df[df.Parameter.isin(v.index[v.gt(5)])]
```

---

For example, where `K = 2` (get all items which have more than 2 readings) -

```
df

   ID Parameter  Value
0   0         A    4.3
1   1         B    3.1
2   2         C    8.9
3   3         A    2.1
4   4         A    3.9
5   5         B    4.5

v = df.Parameter.value_counts()
v

A    3
B    2
C    1
Name: Parameter, dtype: int64

df[df.Parameter.isin(v.index[v.gt(2)])]

   ID Parameter  Value
0   0         A    4.3
3   3         A    2.1
4   4         A    3.9
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) + [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
df[df.groupby('Parameter')['Parameter'].transform('size') > 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

By using `filter`

```
df.groupby('Parameter').filter(lambda x : x['Parameter'].shape[0]>=5)
```

Comment: Unfortuntaely really slow, but plus1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `value_counts()` to get the rows in a DataFrame with their original indexes where the values in for a particular column appear more than once with `Series` manipulation

```
freq = DF['attribute'].value_counts()
# index of items that appear more than once
items = freq[freq>1].index 
more_than_1_df = DF[DF['attribute'].isin(items)]
more_than_1_df
```

Answer (score 2):

Loc with count could also work

```
df.loc[df.Parameter.isin((df.groupby('Parameter').size().Value >= 5).index)]
```