# Pandas: Select rows based on count of index + column pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id    company    ......
111   A
222   B
333   B
111   E
444   C
555   C
555   C
333   A
111   A
222   D
444   C
```

and I would like to get the rows where the `id` occurs in the same `company` at least twice. So the result would be:

```
id    company    .......
111   A
444   C
555   C
555   C
111   A
444   C
```

Although `id 222` was there twice it was with a different company so it is removed. `id 111` was there 3 times but only twice with the same `company`. So only the 2 rows from that `company` remain. And so on.

Rows can occur with the same company more than twice.

There are some stackoverflow questions which deal with selecting rows where a value appears more than once (such as [How to select rows in Pandas dataframe where value appears more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628417/how-to-select-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-where-value-appears-more-than-once)) but I cannot find any that deal with an index + column pair occuring more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 111, 1: 222, 2: 333, 3: 111, 4: 444, 5: 555, 6: 555, 7: 333, 8: 111, 9: 222, 10: 444},
                   'company': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'E', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'D', 10: 'C'}})

print (df[df.duplicated(subset=["id","company"],keep=False)])

#
     id company
0   111       A
4   444       C
5   555       C
6   555       C
8   111       A
10  444       C
```

Comment: TS was mentioning about index not particular columns in dataframe

Comment: I had to reset the index beforehand (`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`) but it worked then. Also used `df.set_index('index', inplace=True)` to get my original index back