# Selecting Rows Based On Specific Condition In Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: dataframe

So I am new to using Python Pandas dataframes.

I have a dataframe with one column representing customer ids and the other holding flavors and satisfaction scores that looks something like this.

[image: Click to view data frame]

Although each customer should have 6 rows dedicated to them, Customer 1 only has 5. How do I create a new dataframe that will only print out customers who have 6 rows?

I tried doing: `df['Customer No'].value_counts() == 6` but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting rows based on a '>' condition of the iteration of one of the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74118560/selecting-rows-based-on-a-condition-of-the-iteration-of-one-of-the-columns)

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

if you post data as a code (preferably) or text, i would be able to share the result

```
# create a temporary column 'c' by grouping on Customer No
# and assigning count to it using transform
# finally, using loc to select rows that has a count eq 6

(df.loc[df.assign(
    c=df.groupby(['Customer No'])['Customer No']
    .transform('count'))['c'].eq(6]
)
```